# Why ffmpeg concat with 2 videos is losing the 2nd audio?

Tags: php, audio, video, ffmpeg, concatenation

i am trying to merge videos (with their respective audios), but when trying to concatenate 2 different video sources, the second audio is not played.

(videos.txt has the 2 videos im trying to concat)

`shell_exec('ffmpeg -f concat -i videos.txt -crf 30 -c:a aac -strict experimental output.mp4');`

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks!!

FFPROBE FOR BOTH FILES:

`ffprobe version N-76417-gee20354 Copyright (c) 2007-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
  configuration: --prefix=/home/dmarcos89/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/home/dmarcos89/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/dmarcos89/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/usr/local/bin --pkg-config-flags=--static --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265
  libavutil      55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
  libavcodec     57. 13.102 / 57. 13.102
  libavformat    57. 13.100 / 57. 13.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 14.101 /  6. 14.101
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.100 /  2.  0.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 't1.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.13.100
  Duration: 00:00:10.14, start: 0.042667, bitrate: 1343 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1183 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 161 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
ffprobe version N-76417-gee20354 Copyright (c) 2007-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.6 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
  configuration: --prefix=/home/dmarcos89/ffmpeg_build --extra-cflags=-I/home/dmarcos89/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/dmarcos89/ffmpeg_build/lib --bindir=/usr/local/bin --pkg-config-flags=--static --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265
  libavutil      55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
  libavcodec     57. 13.102 / 57. 13.102
  libavformat    57. 13.100 / 57. 13.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavfilter     6. 14.101 /  6. 14.101
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.100 /  2.  0.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 't2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.13.100
  Duration: 00:00:07.32, start: 0.042667, bitrate: 3616 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 3487 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 160 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler`

And this is the start of the output message after trying to concat (the entire output is very large and repeats 'Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data...':

`

```
Input #0, concat, from 'videos.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1129 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 639 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 490 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
[libx264 @ 0x2dd3540] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x2dd3540] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 FastShuffle SSE4.2 AVX XOP FMA4 SSEMisalign LZCNT
[libx264 @ 0x2dd3540] profile High, level 3.1
[libx264 @ 0x2dd3540] 264 - core 120 r2151 a3f4407 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2011 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=24 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=30.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.13.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.13.102 libx264
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      encoder         : Lavc57.13.102 aac
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=   43 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:02.28 bitrate=   0.2kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    
frame=   80 fps= 80 q=35.0 size=      44kB time=00:00:03.75 bitrate=  96.0kbits/s dup=1 drop=0    
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0xa559a80] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
[aac @ 0x2daa540] channel element 1.0 is not allocated
Error while decoding stream #0:1: Invalid data found when processing input
```

`

Comment: Paste the full console output of the command, as well as the readouts of `ffprobe` for both the files.

Comment: @Mulvya Updated my question with ffprobe for both files. The only difference i can see from the audio, is that the 1st says '5.1' and the 2nd says 'stereo'... but not sure if this is the cause of my problem. Now pasted the beginning of the console output. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the 2nd video to one having a `5.1` audio stream and then run the concat with the new file.

```
ffmpeg -i t2.mp4 -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict -2 -ac 6 t2-6ch.mp4
```